# Troubles while Creating executable jar file

Tags: java, hibernate, jar, executable-jar

I find out many answers about this question here and on Google but none of them could help me solve my problem.

I'm trying to create a executable jar file from a JSE application using Hibernate and others libs...

I already tried using Eclipse's export, FatJar, Prompt and all I get is the same error that is the following

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
at utils.HibernateUtil_XML.<clinit>(HibernateUtil_XML.java:15)
```

Funny thing that others libraries such as JCalendar is working fine but this one insists.

Does anyone have an ideia what the problem could be?

Comment: Looks like a library did not get imported correctly. Try messing around with your dependencies for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should have all dependencies on the classpath when you are running your jar. Exporting to jar is one thing, running it with proper classpath is another. Look here: [How to Set Classpath for Java on Windows Unix and Linux](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html)

Comment: Thanks guys, I could make it removing the lib folders :)